# How to make three equal div using Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm a student, and my teacher wants to display the news in three equal columns, with two columns, I'm able to get same height,
but when i add third, there's no equality between them.

So I seek some suggestion,
here is the code, :

```
<!-- Latest news -->
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="my-5">Nos dernières actualités</h2>

    <div class="row row-flex">

        {% for new in news %} // This is TWIG vrom Symfony 4.

        {# {% set new = news.order('createdAt desc') %} #}
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="media my-3 shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                <img alt="" class="float-left mr-3" style="width: 2em;" src="{{ path('home')}}img/news/{{ new.image }} ">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">{{ new.title }}</h5>
                    <p>{{ new.title }}</p>
                    <a href="" class="float-right">Lire plus...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `col-md-4` to get three equal columns or simple `col` classes.

```
<div class="section">
    <h2 class="my-5">Nos dernières actualités</h2>

    <div class="row row-flex">

        {% for new in news %} // This is TWIG vrom Symfony 4.

        {# {% set new = news.order('createdAt desc') %} #}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="media my-3 shadow-sm p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">
                <img alt="" class="float-left mr-3" style="width: 2em;" src="{{ path('home')}}img/news/{{ new.image }} ">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="mt-0">{{ new.title }}</h5>
                    <p>{{ new.title }}</p>
                    <a href="" class="float-right">Lire plus...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Change your code with below one and it'll work hopefully